# Zoom out in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a surface plot, and I need this specific point of view that I have chosen. See the image below:

[image]

Now, as you can see, the very bottom part of my axis legend is missing, because matplotlib is cutting it off. Is there any way to programmatically zoom out of the plot so everything fits in the window?

This is my original code:

```
values_all = zip(*values_all)
x = range(len(values_all[0]))
y = range(len(values_all))
figure = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 7))
ax = Axes3D(figure, azim=-124, elev=40, zlim=(0, 0.4))
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
surface = ax.plot_surface(x, y, values_all, linewidth=0, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.colorbar(surface, shrink=0.4, aspect=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimalistic sample code that triggers that issue?

Comment: a `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()` might help

Comment: @MaxNoe this solved the issue!, thank you. provide it as an answer, and I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call

```
 plt.tight_layout()
```

before

```
 plt.show()
```